# Can I join the same 2 dataframe twice using PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pySpark right now. I have 2 table right now. I want to join them twice as shown below.

```
 
Table 1 (df1)

sell_product   sell_amount    buy_product   buy_amount            

apple              2            pineapple        3
pear               1            apple            4
orange             5            apple            2
```

```
 
Table 2 (df2)

product   price                

apple           $1            
pear            $2            
orange          $3       
pineapple       $4
```

```
 
Result Table

sell_product   sell_amount    sell_price        buy_product   buy_amount    buy_price            

apple              2                 $1               pineapple        3       $4
pear               1                 $2               apple            4       $1
orange             5                 $3               apple            2       $1
```

```
df_firstjoin= df1.join(df2.select(col('price').alias('sell_price')),'sell_product'=='product','inner')

df_twice= df1.firstjoin(df2.select(col('price').alias('buy_price')),'buy_product'=='product','inner')
```

I am wondering if there is any way that I can join them at the same time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add two 'price' columns I see no way to do that with one join, because you are using different keys in df1 (sell_product and buy_product). The only solution I can think of is not creating a new df, but do this in a single pipeline.

```
result = df1\
.join(df2.select(col('price').alias('sell_price')),'sell_product'=='product','inner')
.join(df2.select(col('price').alias('buy_price')),'buy_product'=='product','inner')
```